# Angular 2: custom header name is turned to lowercase

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers

`Angular 2 rc.6` written in `typescript 2`

I have a wrapper around the `Http` service that attempts to set custom headers. In the code below, `options` is the `RequestOptions` object I provide to `Http.get()`:

```
//if the content type is not set, use application/json
if(!options.headers.has("Content-Type")){
    options.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json")
}

//set the X-GFX-REQUESTER header
if(!options.headers.has("X-CUSTOM-HEADER")){
    options.headers.append("X-CUSTOM-HEADER", "value");
}
```

When my application makes a request, the browser's (`Firefox 48`) network log shows:

> Content-Type: "application/json"
>
> x-custom-header: "value"

Any idea why the header name would be put to lowercase for the 2nd header?

PS: Thanks for the answers. Really though; doesn't the inconsistency bother anyone else? If `Angular` wants to lowercase headers I set, why not lowercase all headers???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember this was fixed recently to have all-lowercase headers to make it less error-prone. According to the specs headers should not be treated case-sensitive, therefore it shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Interesting. Some APIs ask you to look for info in a specific header. On the server side how can this be implemented in a case-insensitive fashion? For instance, the Dwolla payment service sends  info in the header `X-Dwolla-Signature`. There are about `2^16` possible combinations of upper and lowercase spellings for that.

Comment: just make both lowercase before compairson. This is why it was changed so you can easyly compare lowecase only

Comment: Gunter, on the server-side, headers are accessed as object properties (case-sensitive). So given a `$oHeaders` instance, I can't access the property directly if I don't know its casing.  `$oHeaders->headername` will be undefined while `$oHeaders->HeaderName` or `$oHeaders->HEADERNAME` may be what I need. Anyway I'm venting. I just figured `Angular` wouldn't be this opinionated without giving the user a way to override the lowercasing.  Not to mention that the inconsistency (not all headers are lowercased) seems like poor design.

Comment: I also didn't think this to be a good idea but many insisted and the counter arguments didn't seem too strong, therefore they changed it. I have also seen similar requests elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to be worry about because:

[Rfc2616 standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the
>   field value. Field names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I guess the inconsistency put me off. The `Content-Type` header is not all lowercased. If casing doesn't matter, why does Angular go through the trouble of lowercasing everything?

Answer (score 0):

As @GuntherZochbaer and @igorzg pointed out, the spec requires HTTP header names to be case insensitive. So if my application relies on a specific casing, I should change my application instead of trying to work around `Angular`'s limitations

My basic problem was that my server expected headers to have the same casing that it set previously.  See [this github discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6142#issuecomment-167914781).

My solution (server-side) is to write a custom getters that will return the requested header regardless of casing. Instead of accessing headers directly, I call this getter.

**PHP**

```
/**
 * Provided a request header name, returns the value (case-insensitive fetch).
 * Returns NULL if the header is not found
 */
function fetchHeader($headerName){

    //http request headers: an associative array
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    if($headers===false) return null;

    //lowercase all array keys
    $headers = array_change_key_case($headers,CASE_LOWER);

    $headerName = strtolower($headerName);

    return isset($headers[$headerName])? $headers[$headerName] : null;
}
```